# c++ heap sort for double linked struct

Tags: c++, linked-list

i want to make Heap Sort on a Double Linked List. I could not implement the Heap Sort to my Double Linked List. This list contains student information.

My Code:

```
    // C++ program for implementation of Heap Sort
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct DoubleLinked{
    int number;
    int failCount;
    string name;
    string surname;
    string field;
    DoubleLinked * next;
    DoubleLinked * prev;
} *CompStudents = NULL, *CompIter = NULL;

DoubleLinked* DoubleLinkedInsert(DoubleLinked* temp, int number, string name, string surname, string field, int failCount){
    if(temp == NULL){
        temp = new DoubleLinked;
        temp->number = number;
        temp->name = name;
        temp->surname = surname;
        temp->failCount = failCount;
        temp->field = field;
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->prev = NULL;
        return temp;
    }else{
        CompIter = temp;
        while (CompIter->next != NULL){
            CompIter = CompIter->next;
        }
        CompIter->next = new DoubleLinked;
        CompIter->next->prev = CompIter;
        CompIter = CompIter->next;
        CompIter->number = number;
        CompIter->name = name;
        CompIter->surname = surname;
        CompIter->failCount = failCount;
        CompIter->field = field;
        CompIter->next = NULL;
        return temp;
    }
}

void DoubleLinkedShow(DoubleLinked* temp){
    if(temp != NULL){
        cout << left << setw(13) << "Numara";
        cout << left << setw(18) << "İsim";
        cout << left << setw(14) << "Soyisim";
        cout << left << setw(30) << "Bölüm";
        cout << left << setw(30) << "Dersi Alma Sayısı" << endl;
        CompIter = temp;
        while(CompIter != NULL){
            cout << left << setw(13) << CompIter->number;
            cout << left << setw(18) << CompIter->name;
            cout << left << setw(14) << CompIter->surname;
            cout << left << setw(30) << CompIter->field;
            cout << left << setw(30) << CompIter->failCount << endl;
            CompIter = CompIter->next;
        }
    }else{
        cout << "Öğrenci Bulunamadı. Lütfen Öğrenci Ekleyin." << endl;
    }
}

void InsertAll(){
    cout << left << setw(13) << "Numara";
    cout << left << setw(18) << "İsim";
    cout << left << setw(14) << "Soyisim";
    cout << left << setw(30) << "Bölüm";
    cout << left << setw(30) << "Dersi Alma Sayısı" << endl;
    string line;
    ifstream compFile ("ComputerStudents.txt");
    if (compFile.is_open()){
        while ( getline (compFile,line) ){
            stringstream ss(line);
            vector<string> result;
            while( ss.good() )
            {
                string substr;
                getline( ss, substr, '-' );
                result.push_back( substr );
            }
            cout << left << setw(13) << result[0];
            cout << left << setw(18) << result[1];
            cout << left << setw(14) << result[2];
            cout << left << setw(30) << result[3];
            cout << left << setw(30) << result[4] << endl;
            int no,failCount;
            std::istringstream os(result[0]);
            os >> no;
            std::istringstream os1(result[4]);
            os1 >> failCount;
            CompStudents = DoubleLinkedInsert(CompStudents,no,result[1],result[2],result[3],failCount);
        }
        compFile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Öğrenci Dosyası Bulunamadı.";
}



int DoubleLinkedSize(DoubleLinked* tempSize){
    CompIter = tempSize;
    int i = 0;
    while(CompIter != NULL){
        i++;
        CompIter = CompIter->next;
    }
    return i;
}

void DoubleLinkedSwap(int i,int k,DoubleLinked* swapList){
    DoubleLinked* temp1 = swapList, *temp2 = swapList;
    for(int j = 0; j < i;j++){
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < k;j++){
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }
    int number = temp1->number,failCount = temp1->failCount;
    string name = temp1->name,surname = temp1->surname,field = temp1->field;
    temp1->number = temp2->number;
    temp1->name = temp2->name;
    temp1->surname = temp2->surname;
    temp1->field = temp2->field;
    temp1->failCount = temp2->failCount;

    temp2->number = number;
    temp2->name = name;
    temp2->surname = surname;
    temp2->field = field;
    temp2->failCount = failCount;

}
// To DoubleLinkedHeapify a subtree rooted with node i which is
// an index in arr[]. n is size of heap
void DoubleLinkedHeapify(DoubleLinked* tempHeap, int n, int i)
{
        int largest = i; // Initialize largest as root
        int l = 2*i + 1; // left = 2*i + 1
        int r = 2*i + 2; // right = 2*i + 2
        DoubleLinked* largesti = tempHeap;
        for(int k=0;k<largest;k++){
            largesti = largesti->next;
        }
        DoubleLinked* li = tempHeap;
        for(int k=0;k<l;k++){
            if(li == NULL)
                break;
            li = li->next;
        }
        DoubleLinked* ri = NULL;
        if(li != NULL) ri = li->next;

        // If left child is larger than root
        if (l < n && li->number > largesti->number)
            largest = l;

        // If right child is larger than largest so far
        if (r < n && ri->number > largesti->number)
            largest = r;

        // If largest is not root
        if (largest != i)
        {
            DoubleLinkedSwap(i, largest,tempHeap);

            // Recursively heapify the affected sub-tree
            DoubleLinkedHeapify(tempHeap, n, largest);
        }
}

// main function to do heap sort
void DoubleLinkedHeapSort(DoubleLinked* tempSort, int n)
{
    // Build heap (rearrange array)
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        DoubleLinkedHeapify(tempSort, n, i);

    // One by one extract an element from heap
    for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        DoubleLinkedSwap(0, i,tempSort);

        // call max heapify on the reduced heap
        DoubleLinkedHeapify(tempSort, i, 0);
    }
}



// Driver program
int main()
{
    InsertAll();
    int n;
    n = DoubleLinkedSize(CompStudents);
    DoubleLinked * heaped = CompStudents;
    DoubleLinkedHeapSort(heaped, n);
    cout << "Sorted array is \n";
    DoubleLinkedShow(heaped);
}
```

The base variable is the CompStudents which means "Computer Programming Students". I am holding students in it and i want to sort this list by number variable (small to large).

For example:
This is the print of List. The numbers aren't sorted.

```
Numara       İsim              Soyisim       Bölüm                         Dersi Alma Sayısı             
1030510111   Ömer Faruk        Uslu          Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       0                             
1030516785   Ali               Colak         Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       0                             
1030516450   Mehmet            Böyük         Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       1                             
1030516467   Fatma Reyhan      Sarıkaya      Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       1                             
1030516799   Kemal             Aydın         Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       3                             
1030510113   Zekeriya          Doğan         Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       1                             
1030516786   Emrah             Alkan         Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       0                             
1030516784   Süleyman Özgür    Ozarpacı      Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       0                             
1030516787   Mehmet            Kaynak        Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       2                             
1030516576   Kaan              Soytarıcı     Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       0                             
1030510001   Burcu Ayşen       Kaplan        Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       0                             
1030510003   Ahmet             Kaplan        Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       0
```

Sorting by numbers but it is wrong

```
Numara       İsim              Soyisim       Bölüm                         Dersi Alma Sayısı             
1030510001   Burcu Ayşen       Kaplan        Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       0                             
1030516467   Fatma Reyhan      Sarıkaya      Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       1                             
1030516787   Mehmet            Kaynak        Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       2                             
1030516576   Kaan              Soytarıcı     Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       0                             
1030510113   Zekeriya          Doğan         Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       1                             
1030510003   Ahmet             Kaplan        Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       0                             
1030516784   Süleyman Özgür    Ozarpacı      Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       0                             
1030516785   Ali               Colak         Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       0                             
1030516799   Kemal             Aydın         Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       3                             
1030510111   Ömer Faruk        Uslu          Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       0                             
1030516450   Mehmet            Böyük         Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       1                             
1030516786   Emrah             Alkan         Bilgisayar Mühendisliği       0
```

This is the output.

How can i sort list without affecting CompStudents variable. Thanks.

Comment: "How can i sort list without affecting CompStudents variable"?

You can't. You cannot guarantee the list is sorted if you are not allowed to move the first element.

Comment: You could create a deep copy of the list and sort that.

Comment: Yeah i know i can't sort without affect the variable but i can copy the variable like Temp_CompStudents. In here, the problem is  implementing heap sort. I can't implement to Double Linked List.

Comment: Can you implement a heap sort of an array of `int`? Can you do so with pointers instead of indices? What is the problem?

Comment: I can't use Arrays for this problem. Just Double Linked List allowed for solution. I added some information.

Comment: I am write again an example but it is wrong. I can't understand. What is wrong with my code???

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the checking largest value.

```
if(li != NULL)
    if (l < n && li->number > largesti->number){
        largest = l;
        largesti = li; // This is the what i missed
    }
    // If right child is larger than largest so far
    if(ri != NULL)
    if (r < n && ri->number > largesti->number)
        largest = r;
```